# Using QuickGraph Library in Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, nuget-package

I am trying to use this (https://www.nuget.org/packages/YC.QuickGraph/3.7.4) NuGet package for my Unity project. I have downloaded and added it, but still cannot reference it.

[the package is there,but cannot do anything with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROoN6.jpg)

I ll appreciate any help!Thank you!

Comment: Hi Alex. It looks like you've added the package files directly to your project. IT's hard to be sure from the screenshot but possibly you need to add a reference to the relevant DLL(s) - try right-clicking 'References' => 'Add reference'. If using NuGet you shouldn't need to add the package or the unpackaged files to your project - they should sit in a (non-source-controlled) packages folder outside your project.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!So I 'm posting in case it is useful to someone else.I had to make a new folder in the unity assets(name it Plugins), move all the dlls there, and then reference them from my VS project. Maybe there is a better solution, but this worked...